# Use rvm to execute parameter against many Ruby versions

Tags: ruby, rvm

With most (all?) Ruby interpreters one can write `ruby -we "..."` and have the supplied Ruby code executed (with warnings).

With [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) one can write `rvm ruby foo.rb` and have the source file executed against all installed interpreters.

Is there a way with RVM to run a one-off line of code against all interpreters? I have tried executing both `rvm ruby -we "..."` and `rvm -we ruby "..."` to no good effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`rvm exec`](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/set/exec/).

```
rvm exec ruby -we 'puts "#{`which ruby`.strip} #{RUBY_VERSION}"'
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thanks. I couldn't suss out from `rvm help commands` what `exec` did and I didn't think to use `rvm help exec` to dive deeper.